# Drop rows from dataframe with the values occuring only once in the whole column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['bob', 1], ['james', 4], ['joe', 4], ['joe', 1], ['bob', 3], ['wendy', 5], ['joe', 7]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'score'])
print(df)
```

Looking like:

```
    name  score
0    bob      1
1  james      4
2    joe      4
3    joe      1
4    bob      3
5  wendy      5
6    joe      7
```

I would like to drop all persons with only a single occurrence in a Pythonic way i.e. the result should look like:

```
    name  score
0    bob      1
2    joe      4
3    joe      1
4    bob      3
6    joe      7
```

... and how would I do the same with entries that only have 1 or 2 occurrences? i.e.

```
    name  score
2    joe      4
3    joe      1
6    joe      7
```

Comment: please share the code that you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-nunique) to get count of unique elements in each group & apply `isin` to filter occurrences.

```
g = df.groupby(['name'])['score'].transform('nunique')
```

---

```
df[~g.isin([1])]

  name  score
0  bob      1
2  joe      4
3  joe      1
4  bob      3
6  joe      7
```

---

```
df[~g.isin([1,2])]

  name  score
2  joe      4
3  joe      1
6  joe      7
```